# nodejs/express. regenerate session

Tags: node.js, express

I have a simple nodejs/express application. To save user authentication I use:

```
req.session.auth = user;
```

but [this](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/session.html) I've found regenerate method:

```
req.session.regenerate(function (err) {
   req.session.auth = user;
});
```

My question is: should I use regenerate method or just req.session.auth = user;

Comment: I've found passportjs to be really good at managing authentication and sessions in express applications. http://passportjs.org/

Comment: req.session.regenerate is better prevents session fixation

Comment: auth-flows https://github.com/OhadR/authentication-flows-js  is good at managing this and providing all flows like create account, forgot password etc.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I would lean toward the `req.session.regenerate`, but it depends on what you're trying to do. If you just do `req.session.auth = user`, then you will save the auth to the session. However, if you use `regenerate`, you will actually be clearing the entire session and then saving the auth.

The difference is that with the first approach, any other session variables in the current session will persist. It's up to you to figure out if that makes sense for your site, or if you would rather have the session be clean once authentication is complete.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, you should always use `req.session.regenerate` after user authentication to prevent [session fixation attacks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Types_of_attacks#session_fixation).

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#define_the_lifetime_of_a_cookie), the session cookie should be always regenerated after user authentication. To do this, you must internally change the session ID by regenerating the session.

> If your site authenticates users, it should regenerate and resend session cookies, even ones that already exist, whenever a user authenticates. This approach helps prevent session fixation attacks, where a third party can reuse a user's session.

If you want/need to keep some variables from the previous session, you will need to copy them manually.

```js
let session = req.session;
req.session.regenerate(function (err) {
    req.session.auth = user;
    req.session.some_var = session.some_var;
});
```

More information about the session fixation attack can be found here https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Session_fixation.